# Clarity or Details. Information; what kind of information should I add for a specific question in the main site?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, closed-questions, specific-question

What kind of information does [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/41756/is-wording-a-language-skill-can-it-be-taught-by-a-language-teacher) need; is my motivation in asking the question going to help, should I add it? I earnestly don't know what details and information I should add.

Answer (score 2):

I reviewed your question. It seems like https://writing.stackexchange.com/ would be a better site for it, even if the question is not limited to writing. Linguists do study aspects of language that are related to your question, but as far as I have seen, it is to understand the links between brain capacities and language (in psycholinguistics) or to figure out how to make machines give out the right quantity/quality of information (natural-language generation), and other aspects of that level of abstraction.

In your question, you seem to be seeking personal help, to improve the way you communicate. Linguistics SE is not the right place for that. If you want, I can migrate your question to Writing.SE.

Comment: It is a question of a much broader scope. Psycholinguistics, Sociolinguistics, Neurolinguistics, Stylistics, Cognitive linguistics, Language pathology, Philosophy of language, Computational/Theoretic/Mathematical linguistics, language acquisistion, language acquisistion and dyslexia, autism, neurodevelopmental disorders, langage teaching in general, in adults, in people with dyslexia, autism , neurodevelopmental disorders. I am not asking for personal help. My question wasn't how can I write better (or even how can I use language in general better).

Comment: The question was asking if such an issue is an issue of Language and if a language teacher can help fix it. Are you using the fact that I added my motivation in asking the question against me? The question is about Language and not Writting. If you can guarantee that they will accept the question (I said accept not simply tolerate if the disdain the question they are obviously not accepting it) feel free to migrate my question. I will certainly make use of the answers to get help in my problem (that is what a motivation is everyone has a personal gain).

Comment: I want to satisfy my intellectual curiosity. I want to earnestly understand if this is an issue of Language. Secondarily I hope to make use of the knowledge for my own benefit. It is not a crime or against the rules. No I am not seeking personal help by asking the question. I want an earnest answer (to the question I asked not personal advice) and I want to understand if it is an issue (the abstract issue that I highlighted and that anyone can be subject to and not my personal issue) of language. I am seeking answers (to my question) not advice (for my problem).

Comment: It is not a question about a specific problem. It is a question about an (a relation between a couple of them actually) abstract (non-specific) concept. One abstract concept is wording and an other abstact concept is language skills. Is language skill a proper superset of wording? How do these concepts overlap. I am not asking for advice on how to improve my writing or how to write a specific idea.

Answer (score 1):

[Language learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) addresses not only learning but also teaching of languages. But I have the feeling that the core of the question is not about a skill taught by a language teacher, but a medical problem to be solved by a medical doctor.

Comment: I don't like feelings or intuition. I prefer science (or study). I don't know if the issue is language or not. Is it an issue of Psycholinguistics, Sociolinguistics, Neurolinguistics, Stylistics, Cognitive linguistics, Language pathology, Philosophy of language, Computational/Theoretic/Mathematical linguistics, language acquisistion, language acquisistion and dyslexia, autism, neurodevelopmental disorders, langage teaching in general, in adults, in people with dyslexia, autism , neurodevelopmental disorders?

Comment: I don't know how learning a language is used. By seeing the questions in Language Learning the scope of the question is far of. There is a difference between Language Acquisition and Language Learning. A person that has been speaking a language for almost 30 years and has graduated from University doesn't need to Learn the Language is the sense used by that site. They obviously don't have such an issue. It is a much more nuanced and subtle aspect of language acquisition.

Comment: Psycholinguistics (and Psycholinguistists) are the ones to answer that. But my question is about an (a relation between a couple of them actually) abstract (non-specific) concept. One abstract concept is wording and an other abstact concept is language skills. Is language skill a proper superset of wording? How do these concepts overlap. I don't want to learn a language (particularly not in the way that stack exchange uses learning language).